# RN accessibility on Android - order of how TalkBack reads through View

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, accessibility, talkback

I am trying to use accessibility features in RN and have few questions. How would I get rid of green box in UI, without disabling TalkBack. And the second is - how to enforce the order in which screen reader reads through the elements of view that is composed from several components? At the moment I manipulate state depending on certain parameters and pass it to attributes: accessibilityLabel, accessibilityHint, importantForAccessibility to accomplish that. Is there a better way to do it? 
Here is an example:

```
    this.setState(function(){
       if(<some condition>){
         return{
          accessibilityLabel: "press right to move to other item",
          importantForAccessibility: "yes"
         }
       }else{
          return {
            accessibilityLabel: "something else",
            importantForAccessibility: "no-hide-descendants"
          }
       }
     )}
```

and then

```
render(){
    return(
      <View 
       accessibilityLabel= 
       {this.state.accessibilityLabel}
       importantForAccessibility= 
       {this.state.importantForAccessibility}
      />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How would I get rid of green box in UI, without disabling TalkBack.

The green box is part of Talkback. It's an important feature which makes it clear where the screen reader's cursor is; useful for a variety of disablities including partial sightedness, dyslexia, memory impairments, and attention difficulties.

As a user, it can't be turned off as far as I know. (I have Android Accessibility Suite version 7.2 on Android 8.0). Some screen readers on other platforms offer user preferences to customize the appearance though.

As a developer you can't turn it off either - it's part of Talkback, not the application. This is a good thing; it's the user's assistive technology, not the developer's. Even if a developer could turn off the screen reader's visual cursor, they shouldn't. (It would be like styling a web page with `* { cursor: none !important; }` - mouse users wouldn't thank you for that!)

> how to enforce the order in which screen reader reads through the elements of view that is composed from several components?

When using web browsers, screen readers read web pages in the DOM order, so the general principle which applies to web pages is to make the visual order match the DOM order. (Aside: this is also important for sighted keyboard users, because a tabbing order which differs from the visual order can be very confusing.)

I'm not so familiar with React-native applications, but I would imagine a similar thing applies. You should structure the application's content and controls in a meaningful order. If the application has several regions, mark these up in a way that allows the user to skip to a particular region (with headings, ARIA landmark roles, or possibly other grouping containers). Be aware that screen reader users are not necessarily blind, so the point about visual order and DOM order is important.

It's worth clarifying whether you mean enforcing the "reading order" of the entire application (say, while a user explores the application UI just to see what's there); versus managing focus in response to a particular user action inside a particular widget (like a date picker). Since React-native uses JS, I'd recommend reading [ARIA - Managing Focus](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#managingfocus) to see if this applies to your situation.

Comment: Thank you for very detailed explanation, but it does not directly address the challenges that I am facing. I think the solution of focusing with UIManager in RN docs is more or less workable. It works great on Firestick, but I still did not figure out how to get my KeyEvents of arrow buttons on Android 8 when TalkBack is on. I am new to android so keep learning. Thank you for your time though.

Comment: That stuff wasn't in your question. You originally asked about the reading order, but you didn't indicate that you were using a keyboard to operate it. Like most Windows screen readers, Talkback uses arrow keys to move through the reading order, at a granularity chosen by the user. The exact combination of modifier keys needed for this depends on the user's configuration though. Talkback offers 2 predefined keymaps, and allows the user to customize these too. See https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6110948.

Comment: You may not be able to get programmatic access to the Talkback keyboard commands though (unless RN or Android provides an API for that, I don't really know). JS in a web browser for instance would have no way knowing whether Talkback is being used at all. Using Talkback's arrow key features to advance the reading position needs modifier keys. I'm not sure what you get when pressing the arrow keys on their own. On WIndows screen readers a user may need to activate a special "pass through" mode to send raw keypresses to the application, not sure if Talkback has an equivalent mode.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. It appears that I need to ask this question to an Android Developer. At the time I posted the question I read through React-Native Docs and was limited to attributes. At the time when I posted the comment - to a response - I have dug a little deeper. At this moment I am digging through Android Development Docs as it seems that I need to go a level deeper.